# Alternative for google reCAPTCHA

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, captcha

im looking for nice alternative for google reCaptchta. It would be great if there is a tic tac to game or choosing images or sth like that. I would like it to be simple asp.net controll that I can easily embed on my site and validate it on the server side.

Thank You very much for help

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple search on Google: http://www.getelastic.com/6-captcha-alternatives-to-improve-conversion/
There are 6 alternatives. They include **tic tac game**, too. :p

**Edit:** There are 10 more alternatives: http://woork.blogspot.ro/2009/02/10-free-captcha-scripts-and-services.html

*** * * Edit * * ***

For ASP.NET there are these alternatives:

- http://akismet.com/
- http://mollom.com/